# Conway's game of life: checking neighbours not working properly (c++)

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I've been trying to figure out the problem behind this for a few days. I think it's counting the neighbours incorrectly because when I print the counts, the numbers are mostly 1s and 2s and my output board is completely blank. X ('X') means alive and ' ' means dead.

```
void NextGen(char lifeBoard[][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE], int numRowsInBoard, int numColsInBoard) {
    char nexGenBoard[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];

    // initialize nexGenBoard to blanks spaces
    for(int i = 0; i < numRowsInBoard; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numColsInBoard; j++) {
            nexGenBoard[i][j] = {' '};
        }
    }
    // start from i = 1 and j = 1 to ignore the edge of the board
    for(int i = 1; i < numRowsInBoard-1; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j < numColsInBoard-1; j++) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int y = -1; y < 2; y++) {
                for(int x = -1; x < 2; x++) {
                    if(!(x == 0 || y == 0)) {
                        if(lifeBoard[i+y][j+x] == X) //X is a global constant of 'X'. 
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(lifeBoard[i][j] == X) {
                if(count == 2 || count == 3) {
                    nexGenBoard[i][j] = X;
                }
            }
            else if(lifeBoard[i][j] == ' ') {
                if(count == 3) {
                    nexGenBoard[i][j] = X;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numRowsInBoard; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numColsInBoard; j++) {
            lifeBoard[i][j] = nexGenBoard[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you have been stepping through the program's execution with your debugger, and comparing at each step the values of your variables with the ones that are written down in the design in your notepad. Where do the two diverge?

Comment: `if(!(x == 0 || y == 0)) {` should be `if(!(x == 0 && y == 0)) {` else you're counting only in diagonals

Comment: I did what you said and the counts, now the counts are 1s, 2s, and some 3s. Since the input file I'm using is mostly ' ' (blank) and not Xs, the counts should be mostly 0s. Not sure why count is still incrementing. So I now have four Xs on my board instead of being completely blank and the solutions show probably 20 more Xs than I have

Comment: This is not code review and I realize that you are starting, so take these as hints for a V 0.2: Avoid raw arrays in C++; use vectors or std::array.  Also I would encapsulate the board in a class which shields the manipulating code from implementation details like 'X'. Instead, provide a method `bool isSet(row, column)` and `int countNeighbors()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check during counting `(!(x == 0 || y == 0))` is wrong.  This will not check the square if either x or y is zero.  You want to not count if both x and y are zero.

```
if (!(x == 0 && y == 0))
```

or

```
if (x != 0 || y != 0)
```